# Как сделать такую форму для секции?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

сколько себя помню всегда верстал такие секции след образом. Просто брал картинку в таком формате и ставил как background. Но заказчик хочет что бы в будущем имел возможность менять картинку а форма секции ( круглая ) всегда оставалось таким. Скажите пожалуйста по средствам css, html как сделать что бы при смене фона картинки, фон всегда оставался такой формой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант можно разделить на 2 секции: 1. шапка с кратинкой. 2. вот где белый блок идёт. Белому блоку аналогично бэкраундом делаем псевдоэлемент before и туда вставляем вот эту кривую линию с прозрачным фоном верхним. и получается она будет наезжать у вас на секцию с картинкой и какая бы картинка не была в первой секции "белые волны" всегда будут неизменны

Comment: Либо использовать маску через CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с SVG.

Сгенерировать подходящий SVG можно тут - https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.svg-wave {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-wave svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>logo</h1>
  <h2>We are the best company!</h2>


  <div class="svg-wave">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="">
        <path d="M0.00,49.98 C152.64,-50.81 270.03,253.13 500.00,49.98 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #fff;"></path>
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<h1>BREAK</h1>
<hr>

<div class="bg">
  <div class="svg-wave">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="">
        <path d="M0.00,49.98 C152.64,-50.81 270.03,253.13 500.00,49.98 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #fff;"></path>
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а будет ли работать если у .bg не будет указанной высоты? ( высота зависит от контента )

Comment: Чуть поправил, в примере два варианта, оба без заданной высоты для блока с фоновой картинкой.

Comment: Спасибо большое)